# Assign object variable name to a variable javascript or typescript

Tags: javascript

Can I get a variable name by code,

```
receivedData = { id : 1, name : 'adam', notes : ''};
```

how can I get the variable names in the object "id, name, notes", let's say I want to make a table from the received data and I can't hard code the columns names. is there a way to do this so I can dynamically set the columns names?

```
columnNames = ['id','name','notes'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.keys`

```js
let receivedData = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'adam',
  notes: ''
};

console.log(Object.keys(receivedData))
```

Comment: thank you I already found the answer after posting this question